# Proof by induction (Recursion)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Am really having a hard-time cracking this one. And no, its not homework. Am jst doing more examples in the textbook to see if i get the concept well

It says, we define the polynomial $P_n (x)$ for n being a member of all Natural numbers.

$$\begin{align}
 P_0 (x) &= 1\\
 P_{n + 1} &= (x - 1)P_n (x) + x,  n \geq 0       \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align}$$

1. Find $P_3 (x)$
2. Show that $P_n (3) = 2^{n+2} - 3$

Solving the first part, my approach was that i realized in $\eqref{eq1}$, we have $P_n (x)$ on the R.H.S. A few substitutions and divisions yielded the answer to be

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{P_{n + 1} - x}{(x - 1)} &= P_n (x) \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}$$

I then used $P_3 (x)$ where the value of n was 3 to substitute in $\eqref{eq2}$  and i ended up with

$$\begin{align}
 P_3 (x) &= \frac{P_{3 + 1} - x}{(x - 1)} \\
  &= \frac{P_{4} - x}{(x - 1)} \tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{align}$$
 But i dont know if my interpretation is correct here coz i dont have the value of $P_{4}$

Part 2 defeated me miserably after trying it our on many A4 papers

Comment: For (1) you can just say that $P_3 = (3-1) \cdot P_2 + 3 = (3-1) \cdot ((2-1)P_1 + 2) + 3 = ... $

Comment: That rearrangement doesn't look like it's going to be helpful. To compute $P_3$ you need to know $P_4$, for which you need to know $P_5$... Try going in the other direction - rewriting it as $P_n(x) = (x-1)P_{n-1}(x)+x$. Then, to compute $P_3$ you need to know $P_2$, for which you need to know $P_1$...

Comment: But then, the problem is that it would be quite hard to isolate out what the expression for general n would be. I would end up having a lot of $P_n (x)$ expression all over the place and when i end up factorizing them, i go back to the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that$$P_0(3)=1=2^{0+2}-3.$$On the other hand, if $P_n(3)=2^{n+2}-3$, then\begin{align}P_{n+1}(3)&=(3-1)P_n(3)+3\\&=2\times(2^{n+2}-3)+3\\&=2^{n+3}-3\\&=2^{(n+1)+2}-3.\end{align}

Comment: am finding it quite confusing to see this proof as an inductive process. But then, uv proven it for the base case and it satisfies th equation

Answer (score 1):

From $$ 
 P_0 (x) = 1$$
and 
$$ P_{n + 1} = (x - 1)P_n (x) + x,  n \geq 0 $$

You get,

$$ P_{ 1} = (x - 1)P_0  + x =2x-1$$

$$P_{2} = (x - 1)(2x-1) + x= 2x^2-3x+1$$

You can take over from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you've seen the principle of induction and recursion before, you just need to do like it.

When something is defined recursively like, for example, the numerical sequence $u_{n+1}=u_n+1$ with $u_0=0$, you can conclude all the values of $(u_n)$ by going from the bottom: $u_0=0$ as given, then $u_1=u_0+1=1$, $u_2=u_1+1=2$, and so on...

So in your case, if you want to know $P_3$, get to it from the bottom: you know $P_0(x)=1$, thus $P_1(x)=(x-1)P_0(x)+x=2x-1$. Then use $P_1$ to get the value of $P_2$, and then use it to get $P_3$.

To prove 2., use the principle of induction.